# value does not update after running a function in karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Im new to jasmine/karma, trying to write a test for my angular application and i have a problem that i can't solve, hopefully someone here can help me.

My problem is that my `login()` function updates a value inside my controller but jasmine fails to see the updated value when it's inside `.then()` and the test fails, but when i update the value outside of the `.then()` it passes successfully.

here is my controller:

```
var Authctrl = this;
Authctrl.myVariable = "oldValue";

Authctrl.login = function () {
    AuthService.login(Authctrl.credentials).then(function(authData){
      Authctrl.credentials = { email: '',password: ''};

     /*case 1 */ Authctrl.myVariable = "newValue"; //test gives error 

    },function(error){
        console.log(error);
        Authctrl.errors.login = 'Wrong username or password. Please try again';
    });

    /*case 2 */ Authctrl.myVariable = "newValue"; //test passes successfully

};
```

and my test code:

```
it('should be newValue',function(){
    Authctrl.credentials = {
      email: 'myEmail@yahoo.com',
      password: '12345'
    };

    Authctrl.login();

    expect(Authctrl.myVariable).toBe('newValue');

});
```

and my service:

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {

    return  $q(function(resolve, reject){
      ref.authWithPassword(credentials , function(error, authData) {
        if (error === null) {
          // user authenticated with Firebase
           console.log('SERVICE IS RUNNING, success'); //this does not log when testing with karma
          resolve(authData);
        } else {
          console.log('SERVICE IS RUNNING, error'); //this does not log when testing with karma
          reject(error);

        }
      },{
        remember: "default"
      });//ref.authWithPassword end

      console.log('SERVICE IS RUNNING'); //this logs when testing with karma

    });//$q end
  };//authService.login end
```

Comment: Are you mocking your `AuthService`? What does the full test case look like?

Comment: @MatthewGreen No, im not mocking `AuthService`. do i have to do that?  i made a dummy variable inside my `AuthService` and karma was able to read the value through my controller , so i thought i dont need to mock it and `Authctrl.login()` would execute `AuthService.login()`.

Comment: I usually mock out services so that I'm only testing the controller and nothing else external to it. Are you sure the success part of the promise is called? Is your `credentials` variable also not set?

Comment: @MatthewGreen thats a good idea to mock the service, i think i'm going to do that, but i still want to know where is the source of the error.

Comment: also added my service code, it is running because it logs , but not when inside the  `ref.authWithPassword`.maybe it has something to do with firebase.

Comment: You may have to call a $rootScope.$apply(); in your test for the promise to be resolve exemple here http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/vjJmY/ . Also if your service send data to a server or is asynchronous jasmine won't like that (test end before async finish) you have to use done in jasmine 2, but it will require change in your actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally figured this out and decided to post the answer here in case others run into the same problem. as @MatthewGreen mentioned, i had to create a mock service. and use the `$provide` to define mock AuthService methods and their return values. i followed many tutorials online and i kept getting errors, then i learnt that few things have changed in new jasmine and one of them is the `spyOn` command. [This tutorial](http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/) helped me a lot.

```
    'use strict';

    describe('Controller: AuthCtrl', function () {

      var $rootScope,$scope,$controller,AuthService,AuthCtrl;

      //fake firebase user data
      var mockAuthData = {
        provider: 'password',
        password:{
          email: 'myEmail@yahoo.com',
          isTemporaryPassword: false
        },
        auth:{
          provider:'password',
          uid:'simplelogin:1'
        },
        uid:'simplelogin:1'
      };



      beforeEach(function() {
        module('myApp');

        // Provide will help us create fake implementations for our dependencies
        module(function($provide) {
          // Fake AuthService Implementation returning a promise
          $provide.value('AuthService', {
            login:function(){
              return{
                then:function(callback){return callback(mockAuthData);}
              };
            }
          });
          return null;
        });
      });


      // load the controller's module
      beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _AuthService_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        AuthService = _AuthService_;

        AuthCtrl = $controller('AuthCtrl',
          {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $scope, 'AuthService': AuthService});
          $rootScope.$apply(); 
      }));



      it("myVariable should be newValue", function() {

        spyOn(AuthService, 'login').and.callThrough();

        AuthCtrl.login();

        expect(AuthService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();

        expect(AuthCtrl.myVariable).toBe('newValue');
      });



      it("should retrieve the email address", function() {

        spyOn(AuthService, 'login').and.callThrough();


        AuthCtrl.login();

        expect(AuthService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();

        expect(AuthCtrl.userEmail).toBe('myEmail@yahoo.com');
      });;


    });
```